# Can /mnt/hgfs/'shared folder' be used as apache root?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, apache-httpd, vmware

I have an Ubuntu Server (12.04) running on my development machine.  It is in a VM.  I have succeeded with the task of setting up Apache2, MySQL, and PHP. I can access the server from my host browser by pointing it to the IP. Hurray!

My next task is to set up the filesystem so that I can edit project files on my host computer (Mac OS X 10.7) hit save and view them in my browser through the Linux server.

How I am trying to accomplish this is by sharing a folder on my Mac with the VM, which mounts to `/mnt/hgfs/foldername`.  Then I pointed my virtual host in Apache2 to that folder.  `chmod` the folder to `777` for testing purposes and tried to access the files from my Mac.  I get a `403 Forbidden`.

How can I set up the VM to share a folder with my Mac so that I don't have to FTP all my files to the server?  A thought a had was `rsync` the `/mnt/hgfs/*` folder to the `public_html`

Comment: could you do a test and point your apache to a local (unmounted) folder? If this works, then the issue may just be the apache user not having access to your mount. Could you also post a copy of your /etc/fstab

Comment: @Rqomey Yes, when I point apache to a local (unmounted) folder it work fine! And yes, apache user not having access to your mount, but I can't change owner and group, I have `permission denied`

Comment: Do chmod 777 from the mac.

Comment: @totti I do. But why? The permissions already `777`. Problems with owner

Comment: @brainforce Could you post the contents of /etc/fstab I suspect you have a mounting option which is limiting your permissions.

Comment: Similiar solved problems [1](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38891) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375114/running-xampp-on-windows-through-vmware-fusion-on-a-mac-how-do-i-configure-apac). In [virtual ](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38891)

Comment: @Rqomey I add to question content of `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @totti Thanks, but in second link I do all 3 items in answer and has no result

Comment: Thanks for all, the are solution of my problem: [vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared](http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2013/07/vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared.html)

Comment: May be apache has trouble with network filesystem. So you can try: From linux , create a script that `rsync` all data from network to local file system, And that local data is used by apache

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure Apache has permissions all the way down to the public folder. Other then that it should wok fine, I do it all the time.

`cmhod o+rx /mnt`
`chmod o+rx /mnt/hgfs/`
`chmod o+rx /mnt/hgfs/foldername`

apache probable can't get into mnt

Comment: Thanks for review! I has permissions 777 for all folder, but error is still exist. I think problem is that owner of current dir and all files in it is a **502**, and the group of **dialout**. And I cant execute **chown** command, get an error: **Operation not permitted**.

Comment: what is the permissions for every folder in the path?

Comment: Permissions are `777`, owner - `502` (I think it's my current user id from mac), group - `dialout`. And I can change only permisstions, not owner or group

Comment: does user  502 exist locally? is apache in the dialout group? As far as apache can tell there's no different between a mount and a local folder.  It must be a permission issue. Is any of it a symlink?

Comment: No, locally `502` doesn't exists. Permissions are `777` for all folders and files. I think when I sync it with my Mac OS host machine and Ubuntu on VirtualBox - the owner and group stands by mac os, not Ubuntu.

Comment: When Apache does it's check it checks local groups and users, try creating a user with the id of 502 and see if that helps.

Comment: How can I create user with ID `502`? ID autogenerated in ubnutu, isn't it?

Comment: `sudo adduser mbp -u 502` should do it.

Comment: Yes, it work. But when I try to do something with files I get "Permissions denies"